# Joomla 2.5! Unable to use category field

Tags: joomla, field, joomla2.5, categories, joomla-extensions

I am developing a component I want to add a field to choose a category.I followed this tutorial [Adding categories](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_categories):

```
<field
        name="catid"
        type="category"
        extension="com_mycom"
        class="inputbox"
        default=""
        label="JCATEGORY" 
        description="JFIELD_CATEGORY_DESC"
        required="true"
/>
```

But i only get an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct, but have you added any categories?

This is the kind of thing you can build in minutes using the Joomla Component Creator BTW. http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code at all. However if you are referring to categories that Joomla articles belong to, then you will need to change `extension="com_mycom"` to `extension="com_content"`

Comment: Yes. with com_content, i 'll get categories of com_content. My problem is in how to create categories for my own component. I get difficult in add submenu to create those categories